# asymptotic distribution of quadratic form

Tags: asymptotics, quadratics

I am considering the asymptotic distribution of the following statistics the
form 
$
\
\Gamma =\frac{1}{\sqrt{nm}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{u}_{i}^{T}\mathbf{A}_{m}%
\mathbf{u}_{i},
\
$
where $\mathbf{u}_{i}=\left( u_{i1},\ldots ,u_{im}\right) ^{\prime }$ is
vector of independently distributed idiosyncratic errors and $\mathbf{A}_{m}$ is a $%
m\times m$ bounded matrix. Is there any reference of establishing the
limiting distribution of $\Gamma ,$ i.e., the distribution of $\Gamma $ when 
$n$ and $m$ go to $\infty $ (could be jointly or sequentially)? Any
reference on this? Thanks a lot!